# How would I add stack tracing to my current Redux Devtools setup?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-thunk, redux-devtools

Here is my current redux store assignment:

```
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react';
import reduxThunk from 'redux-thunk';

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, reducers);

const store = createStore(
  persistedReducer,
  composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(reduxThunk)),
);
```

I'd like to be able to stack trace within my project using [Redux Devtools](https://dev.to/finallynero/redux-action-stack-trace-1m0d). The examples given don't really match my setup and was just wondering how I would go about in adding something like the `trace` property without totally rewriting my variable assignment to match theirs.

Comment: You followed the setup instructions [here](https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension)? Or perhaps just upgrade to [redux-toolkit](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/) which has the redux devtools configured by default.

Comment: @DrewReese The former. But if you notice here: https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension#13-use-redux-devtools-extension-package-from-npm, there's no indication of where to add additional options.

Comment: Are you referring to these [configuration options](https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension/blob/master/docs/API/Arguments.md#windowdevtoolsextensionconfig)?

Comment: IMO you should try adding redux-toolkit to your project and switch over to it. It's setup/configuration process is an order or two of magnitude easier to grok and use, and it's trivially simple. It took only about 20 minutes to add to a fairly mature work project and we've not looked back at "legacy" redux since.

Comment: I can definitely give that a look. To answer your original question, yes. The only problem is that normally you'd pass an object of those options. With my current configuration I'm not 100% where to do this.

Comment: `const composeEnhancers = composeWithDevTools(options);` Looks like it is this `options` object.

Comment: Yeah but notice that I'm inserting `applyMiddleware(reduxThunk)` as my sole argument. I'm having a hard time finding what this function returns to figure out a way to combine it's output with the `options` object shown there.

Comment: Yes, and to be quite honest, I also found this aspect of "legacy" redux very unclear. It looks as though you can pass just about anything, in any order, to `createStore` and it works. IMO, not very intuitive.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting options to `composeWithDevTools` and then dropping that into `createStore`?

```js
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';

const composeEnhancers = composeWithDevTools({trace: true}); // <<< set options here

const store = createStore(
  reducer, /* preloadedState, */
  composeEnhancers( // <<< use it here
    applyMiddleware(...middleware),
  )
);
```